# Getting Error while publishing: Transport Service failed to Transport : Tridion 2013 SP1

Tags: 2013, 2013-sp1

I have installed the Tridion 2013 SP1.Then I configured the content deployer.
After this when I publish any item I am getting this error.

```
ERROR TransportService - Unable to establish transport to destination.
com.tridion.transport.TransportException: Unable to retrieve destination metadata

Error Log:[Incoming Folder]
2014-12-23 13:39:38,613 ERROR TransportService - Unable to establish transport to destination.
com.tridion.transport.TransportException: Unable to retrieve destination metadata
    at com.tridion.transport.DestinationController.<init>(DestinationController.java:116) ~[cd_transport.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.transport.DestinationControllerFactory.getDestinationController(DestinationControllerFactory.java:41) ~[cd_transport.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.transport.model.transaction.context.TransactionProcessor.createOrLoadTransaction(TransactionProcessor.java:134) ~[cd_transport.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.transport.model.transaction.context.TransactionProcessor.<init>(TransactionProcessor.java:48) ~[cd_transport.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.transport.TransportService.handleTransaction(TransportService.java:253) ~[cd_transport.jar:na]
Caused by: com.tridion.configuration.ConfigurationException: Unknown connector type: Content
    at com.tridion.transport.connection.pooling.TransportPoolManager.createTransporterInstance(TransportPoolManager.java:229) ~[cd_transport.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.transport.connection.pooling.TransportPoolManager.getTransporterConnector(TransportPoolManager.java:174) ~[cd_transport.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.transport.workers.EndpointMetaWorker.getMetadata(EndpointMetaWorker.java:32) ~[cd_transport.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.transport.DestinationController.<init>(DestinationController.java:108) ~[cd_transport.jar:na]
    ... 4 common frames omitted![enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: "Unknown connector type: Content" - what did you set up as protocol in your publication target?

Answer (score 4):

First of all check whether you are able to hit httpupload.aspx page from CM server side, if this page get render then you have to verify your publication target steps because this error comes only when there is an issue with protocol selection, username , password and fully specified URL to upload page.

Comment: Yes it was for user credential.
I changed the IIS setting for httpupload web site and now it is working.

Comment: Really great !!!

Comment: I had http:\\localhost:80\HTTPUpload.aspx instead of http://localhost:80/HTTPUpload.aspx in the publishing target & got this error.